# MVVM EventToCommand Parameter is NULL

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM Light Toolkit in Windows Phone 7.1

Part of ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<object> ChangeVATCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _changeVATCommand
                    ?? (_changeVATCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                                          (vat) =>
                                          {

                                          }));
            }
        }
```

Part of Xaml:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker  ItemsSource="{Binding VATs}" x:Name="VATs" SelectedIndex="0"  DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ChangeVATCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=VATs}"
                />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

When command is running a vat passed to lambda is null. If I set in xaml CommandParameter to "{Binding ElementName=VATs}" then vat in lambda have ListPicker with right property SelectedItem object (not null).

### This is a bug or I doing something wrong?

UPDATE

Summary:

1. CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=VATs}" - I have NULL
2. CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=VATs}" - works fine! I have index of selected vat
3. CommandParameter="{Binding ,ElementName=VATs}" - works fine! I have ListPicker with proper selecteditem

Comment: Thanks you. I work for the second option -CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=VATs}"

Answer (score 3):

I would rather recommend binding the ListPicker's SelectedItem with a two way binding to a property on your VM. Then from the Command, you can easily access this property.

If you choose this solution, you probably don't even need the Command, you can trigger your calculation directly from within the SelectedItem property in the VM.

Cheers
Laurent

Comment: Of course this is better approach to achieve my goal. Less code less bugs!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem not long ago, the solution was indicating the corresponting VM:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker  ItemsSource="{Binding VATs}" x:Name="VATs" SelectedIndex="0"  DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ViewModelName.ChangeVATCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=VATs}"
            />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Notice that now the binding references the ViewModel and uses the Locator as source.

Comment: I made your changes but vat is still NULL. Its strange because eg SelectedIndex (CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=VATs}") property is proper passed to command

Comment: If you want to receive the selectedItem can you please try `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding}" pass entire viewmodel because this is a datacontext of trigger/element. I checked this anyway...